# filter ChoiceField dynamically based on another field

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms

**SOLVED** 
thanks a lot to Abdul Aziz Barkat who in his comment posted a link to a perfect tutorial.
basically I created a view that gives me the small part of html that corresponds to the list of filtered data and I used ajax calls to reload only that portion of the template. below I leave the link to the guide for more explanations:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html.

---

I have a Model Form that must be filled in by the user.
in the form there are 3 drop-down menus (foreignkey in the model) which depend on each other. that is, when the user selects a value in the first field the results in the second must dynamically depend on that.
i know i have to use ajax but i never used it and i don't know where to start

I know that to filter I have to set the queryset e.g. `form.fields['stabilimento'].queryset = Stabilimento.objects.filter()`, but I don't know how to do it using ajax

**model.py**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    stabilimento = models.ForeignKey(Stabilimento, on_delete = models.RESTRICT)
    linea = models.ForeignKey(Linea, on_delete = models.RESTRICT)
    macchina = models.ForeignKey(Macchina, on_delete = models.RESTRICT)
```

**form.py**

```
class NewTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: See this tutorial on Simple is Better than Complex: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: thank you very much, exactly what I needed